# Determine the sign of Gaussian curvature

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curvature, gaussian-measure

I calculated the Gaussian curvature of a metric and obtained the following expression
$$ 
\kappa(r, Q) 
= \frac{2 \chi E^2 r^2 Q^2 
\bigl[ r^2 \xi \!+\! m^2 Q^2 (r^2 \!+\! 2Q^2) 
\!+\! r^4(E^2\!-\!m^2) \bigr] 
\!+\! \zeta \xi (r^2 \!+\! Q^2) 
\bigl[ (r^2 \!+\! Q^2) \xi \!+\! E^2 r^2 Q^2\bigr]\!\!} 
{2 r^4(r^2 \!+\! Q^2) \xi^3} 
$$
where
\begin{align}
\xi &= E^2 r^2 - m^2 (r^2 + Q^2) \\
\chi &= r^2 - rb + Q^2 \\
\zeta &= r(rb' - b) + 2Q^2.
\end{align}

where the primed symbol means derivative with respect to $r$, i.e. $b'(r) = \frac{d b(r)}{d r}$, $b(r) = 1 / r^{q}$ para $q>0$ y que $E > 0$.

I understand that the sign of the curvature will depend not only on $r$ and $Q$ but also on $b$, $b'$, and $m$. Is there any technique or way to determine the sign of the Gaussian curvature of expressions this complicated? Could anyone give me a suggestion or recommendation? I searched around on some articles without success.

Comment: In what sense is this a Riemannian metric?

Comment: @MoisheKohan No, I mean I got it from a Riemannian metric

Comment: Oh, I see. If you are interested in a specific point, you can use Mathematica for such calculation. But in general one needs more information about the surface and the metric. On general grounds, one expects variable sign of the curvature. Also, information about the functions $b, E$ is missing.

Comment: @MoisheKohan The only information I have is that $b(r) = 1 / r^{q}$ for $q>0$ and that $E > 0$. I would just like to know if there is any criterion to know in which regions it is positive or negative instead of calculating point by point.

Comment: What’s the formula for the metric?

Comment: @Deane the metric is 
$$ d s^{2} = \left(E^2 - m^2 \left(1 + \frac{Q^{2}}{r^{2}}\right)\right) \left( 1 + \frac{Q^{2}}{r^{2}} \right)^{-1} \left[ \left( 1 - \frac{b(r)}{r} + \frac{Q^{2}}{r^{2}} \right)^{-1} d r^{2} + r^{2} d \phi^{2} \right] $$

Comment: Your metric is of the form $a^2(b^2\,dr^2 + r^2\,d\phi)^2)$, where $a$ and $b$ are functions of $r$ only. I suggest first computing the Gauss curvature of $g = a^2h$ and figuring out how the sign of the Gauss curvature of $g$ depends on $a$ and the Gauss curvature of $h$. Then compute the Gauss curvature of $h$ and apply the criteria you found in the first step.

Comment: @Deane What do you mean with $h$? Or do you mean $h = (b^2 d r^{2} + r^2 d \phi^2)$?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: @Deane So what I did was first calculate the Gaussian curvature for $h(r)$ omitting $a^2(r)$ and I got

$$ K_{h} = - \frac{(4 Q^2 + 2 r^2 - 3 r b(r) + r^2 b'(r))}{2 r^{3} (1 - \frac{b(r)}{r} + \frac{Q^2}{r^2})^2} $$

But from $a^2(r) = \left(E^2 - m^2 \left(1 + \frac{Q^{2}}{r^{2}}\right)\right) \left( 1 + \frac{Q^{2}}{r^{2}} \right)^{-1} $ you could know its behavior for specific values of $Q$, $m$ and $E$ but not its Gaussian curvature since it is only a function $f(r)$ but not a surface. Could you be a little more detailed, please? I'm sorry if I can't understand you completely.

Comment: Now compute the general formula for $K_g$ in terms of $K_h, a, b$ without substituting your formulas for them. Not sure this would work but might as well try.